# ASP.net core EF-Core model creation error

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am totally new to ASP.net core development. I am building a Web API using EF-Core and Mysql in the backend.

My class diagram looks like following:
[image]

I have created model class like following:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace New_Api.Models
{

    public class CoreGoal
    {
        public int CoreGoalId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public List<string> Steps { get; set; }
        public List<string> Benefits { get; set; }
        public List<string> Effect { get; set; }
        public List<string> Images { get; set; }

        public List<SubGoal> SubGoals { get; set; }

    }

    public class SubGoal
    {
        public int SubGoalId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Priority { get; set; }
        public List<string> Issues { get; set; }

        public CoreGoal CoreGoal { get; set; }

    }

    public class WebAPIDataContext : DbContext
    {
        public WebAPIDataContext(DbContextOptions<WebAPIDataContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CoreGoal> CoreGoals { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SubGoal> SubGoals { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<CoreGoal>()
            .HasMany(b => b.SubGoals)
            .WithOne();
        }
    }

}
```

When I build this using Ctrl+F5 it gives me error that List is not a primitive data type.

I have a couple of questions:

1. After modifying a class file, do I have to migrate before building the solution?
2. Looking at the class diagram, am I writing the models and their relationships in a correct way?
3. What am I doing wrong with array attribute on my models?

Comment: `Step`, `Benefit` etc. must be classes, not strings. Like `SubGoal`.

Comment: Okay! Now it is clear, I do the same in Django. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Collection of scalar types (`List<string>`) is not yet supported https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4179

Comment: Sure thanks! I will take a look